# Entity - how to get only one column

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Is there any possibility to get only one column from `.Where` statement? For example - `ID`.

```
List<testB> test = db.testB.Where(x => x.UserID == userId).ToList();
```

Here I get all entites `testB`.

And I just want to return `List<int>` with `testB.ID` instead of `List<testB>`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use Linq's `Select` method to _project_ (see tooltip help for Select method) your selection into a list of `int`, like in @StevenVondruska's answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
db.testB.Where(x => x.UserID == userId).Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
```

should return a `List<int>`

Comment: It's going to return a `List` of whatever type `x.ID` is.

Comment: @retailcoder It was implied in the question ID was of type int.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .select like this

```
var test = db.testB.Where(x => x.UserID == userId)
    .Select(a => new {
          column = a.column
    }).ToList();
```

this creates an anonymous type class of only on attribute. Try it out.

Comment: This won't work because you've done Select before Where - the UserId column doesn't exist after the Select part.  You would normally do the `Where` before the `Select`, as in Steven's answer

Comment: You are right. I just updated the answer. it should work now.

Comment: This is not a valid answer for the question. it would not return a `List<int>`